# Events don't render in agendaWeek nor agendaDay views in Fullcalendar

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

Events render properly in month, basicWeek, and basicDay views; however, events with allDay set to false (have specific times) do not appear in agendaweek nor agendaDay views.  I’ve inspected the JSON and confirmed that allDay is set properly as a Boolean value.    alldayDefault is set to false.  I’ve even defined specific time intervals for both agendaWeek and agendaDay views.  I’ve googled the heck out of the issue and current solutions tend to stem from treatment of the allDayDefault or allDaySlot parameters.  None appear to be issues for me.  Would appreciate any insights.`

```
    <script> 
    $(document).ready(function() {

        var date = new Date();
        var d = date.getDate();
        var m = date.getMonth();
        var y = date.getFullYear();


        var calendar = $("#calendar").fullCalendar({
            defaultView: "month",
            weekends: true,
            minTime: 6,
            maxTime: 23,
            height: 620,
            allDayDefault: false,
            header: {
                    left: "prev,next today",
                    center: "title",
                    right: "month,agendaWeek,agendaDay"
            },
            editable: true,
            events: "../getCalendarEvents.php",
            eventLimit: true,
            views: {
                agendaWeek: {
                    minTime: 6,
                    maxTime: 23
                },
                agendaDay: {
                    minTime: 6,
                    maxTime: 23
                }
            },


            // Convert the allDay from string to boolean
            eventRender: function(event, element, view) {
                if (event.allDay === 'true') 
                {
                    event.allDay = true;
                } else 
                {
                    event.allDay = false;
                }
            },

            selectable: true,
            selectHelper: true,
            select: function(start, end, allDay) 
            {
                var start = moment(start).format("MM/DD/YYYY");
                var end   = moment(end).format("MM/DD/YYYY");
                window.location = 'calendar_addEvent_template.php?start=' + start + '&end=' + end;
                calendar.fullCalendar('unselect');
            },

            eventDrop: function(event, delta) 
            {
               var start = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.start, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
               var end = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.end, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
               $.ajax({
                   url: '../eventUpdate.php',
                   data: 'title='+ event.title+'&start='+ start +'&end='+ end +'&id='+ event.id ,
                   type: "POST",
                   success: function(json) 
                   {
                        alert("Updated Successfully");
                   }
               });
            },

            eventResize: function(event) {
               var start = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.start, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
               var end = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.end, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
               $.ajax({
                    url: 'eventUpdate.php',
                    data: 'title='+ event.title+'&start='+ start +'&end='+ end +'&id='+ event.id ,
                    type: "POST",
                    success: function(json) 
                    {
                        alert("Updated Successfully");
                    }
               });

            }

      });

 });
```

Answer (score 1):

I keep teaching myself the same lessons over and over. Read The *( Manual!

I changed my view specific options for mintime and maxtime

From

```
    views: {
                week: {
                    minTime: "6”,
                    maxTime: "23"
                },
                day: {
                    minTime: "6",
                    maxTime: "23"
                }
            },
```

TO

```
    views: {
                week: {
                    minTime: "06:00:00",
                    maxTime: "23:00:00"
                },
                day: {
                    minTime: "06:00:00",
                    maxTime: "23:00:00"
                }
            },
```

AND VIOLA!  I hope this saves someone some time.

Answer (score 0):

Are you loading your events in this format? I know you mentioned you did, but to double check it as your code seems to work find for me with some added events, at least on jFiddle (note be sure to use these exact references at first, as even changing the jQuery version seems to cause odd bugs):

```
<script src="http://www.arshaw.com/js/fullcalendar-1.5.3/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://arshaw.com/js/fullcalendar-1.5.3/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/omikey/pm4ajohL/

Comment: Thanks @oMiKey, indeed I've checked the JSON and the format is correct.   I'm running Fullcalendar version 2.3.2 and jQuery version 2.1.4. I've downloaded the files and serve them up locally.